# using Sphinx's sphinx-apidoc utility to autogenerate documentation from python code

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-apidoc

I am wondering what the commenting format is in order to have self-documenting code using Sphinx's sphinx-apidoc utility.  I am able to get this utility to generate a set of reStructuredText files for each python file, but these files still need to be filled in.  I am looking for a way to get this utility, or some other Sphinx utility to generate documentation from the python codes docstrings.  I understand this would require becoming familiar with a conventional commenting format, and I am hoping to be pointed to this reference material.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen these? http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html?info-field-lists#info-field-lists, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4547849/407651.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mzjn, thanks for the comment.  your second link provided some good insight on how to format **docstrings**.

furthermore, i failed to mark the proper **sphinx-quickstart** prompt answers (as specified in the link, http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#full-code-example).  particularly, answering **yes** to:

**autodoc: automatically insert docstrings from modules (y/N) [n]:**

also, as noted in the link, http://codeandchaos.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/sphinx-autodoc-tutorial-for-dummies/,  and the **conf.py** comments, i needed to append locations of modules to the system path.  i should note that i ran into a problem appending filenames.  when i appended paths where modules could be found, everything worked perfectly.